# How do I deal with static navbars in Node?

Tags: html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

A bit about my background: I haven't done much web development for a while, and am only recently starting to get back in the swing of things. I remember the days when I used to have static header/footer files in PHP, and code like so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include("header.php") ?>
Body text here
<?php include("footer.php") ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm currently making the switch to **Node for my backend** (for various reasons not pertinent to this post). I'm still quite new at this, so I'm wondering if there is a simple way to go about having static headers/footers (which contains navbars and such) for my front end. I'm trying to use **Bootstrap** for my front end framework.

I think using Jade, or other template engines, might be one way to go about doing this, though I'm not necessarily sure if I want to use Jade just yet as dealing with js and HTML is troublesome enough without adding another pseudo-language/format/template into the mix. **So I'm wondering if there is a solution that does *not* use template engines.**

Here's what I currently have for my app.js/web.js file:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs');

var bodyparser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

app.get('/submit', function(req,res) {  
    [functions omitted for brevity]
})

[other processes omitted for brevity]

app.listen(8080)
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can go with `Jade` and use its `includes` to include different parts into one page. Here is the official documentation on `Jade includes`: http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this without using template engines though?

Comment: I think no, but if you want to have a `PHP-like` templates, you can use `EJS` template engine, which is much similar to `PHP` templates' syntax. Here it is: http://www.embeddedjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend to use a view engine for this. Node is not like PHP. PHP scripts are processed sequentially and the rendered output is sent as the response. If you were to do the same approach in node you would be building a string in JavaScript and then sending it out to the client.

```
app.get('/submit', function(req,res) {  
    var output = '<html>';
    output += '<head>';
    ...
    res.send(output);
});
```

Now imagine that you have to query a database:

```
app.get('/submit', function(req,res) {  
    var output = '<html>';
    output += '<head>';
    ...
    db.query(query, function(err, result) {
       output += 'the result is ' + result;
       ...
       res.send(output);
    });
});
```

So the lesson is, use a templating engine as they are designed for building the html output for you. Start with [ejs](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) as it will have a more familiar syntax to php.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, upon further reading, it seems like I can't get around this without using template engines. EJS does look like a good start.